# Expected identifier or '(' error before @class

Tags: iphone

I have these 2 classes:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UICustomButton.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>{
...
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
...
```

UICustomButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface UICustomButton : UIButton{
...
```

UICustomButton.m

```
#import "UICustomButton.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation UICustomButton
...
```

And I get the following errors

1 Expected identifier or '(' - in file UICustomButton.h just before @class

2 Expected ')' - also there

3 Expected a type - when I try to use ViewController in UICustomButton.h

4 in UiCustomButton.m I also get the error

After two hours of googling and trying, I just can't see the problem. Can you please help?

SOLUTION: 
Rewriting everything was a good ideea. It made me see that in the file ViewController.m I had accidentally typed a paranthesis '(' on top at the beginning of the file. The compiler didn't poit it out, only UICustomButton.H generated errors.

Comment: Delete your files and restart from scratch. That's the easiest solution. If you have some business logic already implemented, you can move it to the new files. :) For custom buttons, however, have you looked at https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=button there are millions of implementations already, I'm sure you'll find your favorite one.

Comment: Why are you importing `UICustomButton.h` in `ViewController.h`?

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I want to access methods from UICustomButton in ViewController and vice versa. The ViewController contains UICustomButtons.

Comment: @allprog: are you serious w deleting the files? Cause I was debating it myself. It's not a specific custom button, I just have some custom methods inside

Comment: Are you trying to add methods to UIButton? Consider making a "Category" for UIButton.

Comment: @user2555825 you don't need to import headers from headers to do that. Move the `#import UICustomButton.h` to your ViewController.m and see what happens. If that doesn't fix it, you need to provide more code.

Comment: @user2555825 I'm completely serious about you needing to restart creating this class. Since apparently you can't interpret the message that the compiler is telling you it will take much longer for you to figure out the issue than creating another class, copying the business logic there and deleting the current implementation. Your choice, spend 10 minutes recreating the file or spend another who knows many hours trying to get the syntax ok. :) And you can even rename the new class to the old one once you're done.

Comment: @allprog you should write your answer so I can vote it as helpful

Comment: @user2555825 thanks for listening. This is a sign of a good start for you to become a good programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to restart/scrap and recreate a class. As you gain more experience correcting complex errors becomes a lot easier.

I'm completely serious about you needing to restart creating this class. Since apparently you can't interpret the message that the compiler is telling you it will take much longer for you to figure out the issue than creating another class, copying the business logic there and deleting the current implementation. Your choice, spend 10 minutes recreating the file or spend another who knows many hours trying to get the syntax Ok.

Even the professionals feel it a strong tool to restart when it's needed. Marshall Huss from Treehouse explains [in this podcast](http://springboardshow.com/20) why it was preferrable for him too.

PS: and best, you can rename the new class to the old name once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are misspelling ViewController.h. You have Viewcontroller.h in your #import line

Comment: Thanks, it was not that tho. That was just a typo from when I did the post, I guess

Comment: You should edit your question and copy and paste the .h and .m of CustomButton